# Received JSON in Rails API is not stored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am working on a web service in Rails that receives data in JSON format from another Rails application. When the web service receives the data, it reads it but does not insert into the database. This is from the log file:

`Processing by OrdersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"name"=>"dst", "address"=>"dst", "email"=>"sdt"}
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "orders" ("created_at", "updated_at")`

What should I do to get this data inside the INSERT statement? Do I need a new json.jbuilder file or something else? What am I missing?

Update: Putting the controller#create code here. Didn't paste it initially because it is the default created from the scaffold generator.

```
  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @order.save
          format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully       created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
  end
```

Comment: provide controller's (service/model, essentially this part of app which calls save method) code so we can see what is run and why it might not being saved as expected.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can put your code in `OrdersController#create`.

Comment: Updated with code. It is the default generated controller from the scaffold. I wasn't sure if and what need to be added/changed to help with what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order_params` is presumably defined somewhere in your `OrdersController`. Normally model parameters in a request are nested under the resource (`{order: {"name"=>"dst", "address"=>"dst", "email"=>"sdt"}`) and then in `order_params` would be

```
def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:name, :address, :email)
end
```

But if you can't change the JSON payload, you could just nix the `require(:order)` part and call `params.permit(:name, :address, :email)`.

You can read the Rails guide on Strong Parameters here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: Yes, it was the `.permit` call that was required. I had tried with params[:name, :address, :email] but some other error was popping up. I didn't know about .permit so thank you!